# Moving back from Qt5.3 to Qt4.8, having Q_DECLARE_METATYPE issues

Tags: c++, qt

due to requirements at my job, I had to revert by build from Qt5.3 to Qt4.8 and it all went well with a few function changes, except I got `QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype` errors all over. Has anyone else encountered this? I'm baffled, I have no idea where to start. As far as I know, Q_DECLARE_METATYPE is a valid macro in Qt4.8 and works the same way. I haven't changed any includes or anything.

Comment: Since Qt 5.x, the type defined with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` should be a fully defined type. (according to: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sourcebreaks.html)

Comment: It works perfectly on Qt 5.x, the problem starts when I move back to 4.8

Comment: And using `qRegisterMetaType` ?

Comment: Doesn't it have to be called as a function in some initialization call? Isn't Q_DECLARE_METATYPE functional in Qt 4.8? Or must I refactor everything and call qRegisterMetaType for everything in initialization?

Comment: Depends what you want.... 
The macro works for template based stuff, the function works for the signal / slot related stuff

Comment: In our application (Qt 4.7) the macro does not work, the function call does (For use with signals and slots)

Comment: I am trying to pass variables of my custom types as well as their pointers to QVariant, on Qt 5.3 it worked by just putting them in Q_DECLARE_METATYPE, but what exactly do I use on Qt4.3?

Comment: We do not use the QVariant, but only signal / slot related stuff, for that `qRegisterMetaType<std::string>("std::string");` is sufficient.

Comment: Is the string argument nessecary? Also, what do you write in the string argument when it's a pointer, do you write the asterix inside the string?

Comment: Yes, i declare pointers like this: `qRegisterMetaType<std::string*>("std::string*");`. Qt warns me on the console with a type that is not defined, so try defining one first before you change your entire application.

Comment: ok thanks, one last question - does it work on templates, for instance: qRegisterMetaType<QList<MyType*> >("QList<MyType*>)

Comment: This is a horrible question without a test case that reproduces your specific problem. Since everyone can come up easily with a test case that works, it's anyone's guess as to what you might be doing wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works identically in Qt 4 and Qt 5. I'm not sure what you're doing wrong - it's hard to imagine one cause from a vast array of snafus without seeing some code. "I just wrote a bunch of code in Qt 5 and it doesn't work in Qt 4" is a bit vague, you must admit.

```
#include <QtCore>

struct T {};

class C : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QList<T*> stuff READ stuff)
   QList<T*> m_stuff;
public:
   C(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) { m_stuff << (T*)10 << (T*)11; }
   Q_SIGNAL void aSignal(const QList<T*>&);
   Q_SLOT void aSlot(const QList<T*>& data) {
      m_stuff = data;
   }
   QList<T*> stuff() const {
      return m_stuff;
   }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<T*>)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   qRegisterMetaType<QList<T*> >();
   C c;
   c.connect(&c, SIGNAL(aSignal(QList<T*>)), SLOT(aSlot(QList<T*>)), Qt::QueuedConnection);

   // Test reading a property
   QMetaProperty p = c.metaObject()->property(c.metaObject()->indexOfProperty("stuff"));
   auto s = p.read(&c).value<QList<T*> >();
   Q_ASSERT(s == c.stuff());

   // Test queued signal-slot connection
   auto const data = QList<T*>() << (T*)1 << (T*)2;
   emit c.aSignal(data);
   a.processEvents();
   Q_ASSERT(data == c.stuff());
   return 0;
}

#include "main.moc"
```